# Some unknown automatic tool added imports to my code

Tags: python

i can't figure out who's the culprit:

today when i edited the code, I found new imports in the source, e.g.

```
from Ipython.something import pprint
from something import retry
```

(the  word "something" is just a fake example for SO - I dont remember the exact modules. They seemed pretty random)

Both "retry" and "pprint" are indeed being used in the code, but they are properly defined and assigned values, e.g. "for retry in somelist:", or "from pprint import pprint" that occurs in this case only inside the method (which might explain why some robotic syntax checker might think it's not imported...)

I assume an automatic process decided, without asking my permissin, that I need to import "retry", and chose the next bogus module to import it from. What the hell.

Of course the imports were incorrect, some of the imported modules didn't even exist, or refered to inexistent variables ("from something import MIN" - but I dont have "MIN" anywhere in my code!).

Which kind of tool is capable of adding imports to one's code?

I'm using:

- ubuntu 12
- aptana 3.4 (with preconfigured pydev)
- python 2.7.3
- pylint (for checking the code manually from the command line)
- svn

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would guess that the most likely one to blame is aptana - a quick check using svn blame is worth running to see when they appeared.

Comment: as with @steve's answer, it's probably pydev, an eclipse/aptana module. in preferences > pydev > somewhere, there's an option to disable "auto imports"